# Firestore iOS queryWhereField and queryOrderedByField is not returning specific data

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my iOS project, I'm using Firestore. I'm in need to use queryWhereField and queryOrderedByField, I've implemented as follows but it's not working:

```
defFirestore = [FIRFirestore firestore];
colRef = [defFirestore collectionWithPath:@"walks"];
[[[colRef queryWhereField:@"requestId" isEqualTo:@(self.requestId)] queryWhereField:@"taskId" isEqualTo:@(self.taskId)] queryOrderedByField:@"createdDate"];
[colRef getDocumentsWithCompletion:^(FIRQuerySnapshot * _Nullable snapshot, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error getting documents: %@", error);
    } else {
        for (FIRDocumentSnapshot *document in snapshot.documents) {
            NSLog(@"%@ => %@", document.documentID, document.data);
        }
    }
}];
```

Above query is not returning where specific record rather returning all records also not ordered by **createdDate** field. Firestore database screenshot as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've already figured that out. First of all need to create an index in Firestore for those fields we want to query from. then need to define a FIRQuery to run the query with those fields. So the query will look like as follows:

```
FIRQuery *walks = [[[colRef queryWhereField:@"requestId" isEqualTo:@(self.requestId)] queryWhereField:@"taskId" isEqualTo:@(self.taskId)] queryOrderedByField:@"createdDate"];
[walks addSnapshotListener:^(FIRQuerySnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
    if (snapshot == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching documents: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error getting documents: %@", error);
    } else {
        for (FIRDocumentChange *diff in snapshot.documentChanges) {
            if (diff.type == FIRDocumentChangeTypeAdded) {
                NSLog(@"%@ => %@", diff.document.documentID, diff.document.data);
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

I used snapshot because I want to get realtime update.